# Keycloak initial admin user with email

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I am trying to create default configuration for Keycloak using docker-compose, so that the verify email function works out of the box. For that I created a realm with the configured Email settings, but the problem is, that Keycloak only sends the emails, when I enter my email in the admin console under  -> manage account -> personal info

Is there a way to set the email address in that menu automatically on start up?

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

  reference-app:
    image: reference-service-iaa
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mariadb://db:3306/iaa_reference
      - DATASOURCE_USERNAME=user
      - DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=user
      - KEYCLOAK_SERVER=http://keycloak:8180/auth/

  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: iaa_reference
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user
    volumes:
      - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:15.0.0
    restart: on-failure
    command:
      - "-b"
      - "0.0.0.0"
      - "-Djboss.http.port=8180"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/keycloak/realm-export.json:/tmp/realm-export.json
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=password
      - DB_VENDOR=postgres
      - DB_USER=admin
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - DB_ADDR=keycloak-db
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_DATABASE=keycloakdb
      - KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:8180/auth
      - KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/tmp/realm-export.json
    ports:
      - "8180:8180"
    depends_on:
      - keycloak-db

  keycloak-db:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloakdb
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

**Edit**

SMTP Config from Keycloak:

```
"smtpServer": {
        "password": "**********",
        "replyToDisplayName": "Example Name",
        "starttls": "true",
        "auth": "true",
        "port": "465",
        "host": "smtp.gmail.com",
        "from": "example@gmail.com",
        "ssl": "true",
        "user": "example@gmail.com"
    }
```

Best

Comment: Share your realm-export.json

Comment: It is to long to be shared. Is there a specific part you need to see?

Comment: want to see your smtp configuration

Comment: also what do you mean by email sending to only my email address?

Comment: The email configured in the smtp config, needs to be entered under mange account -> personal info

Comment: make an API call to update user with email address after container is up